# How to reset a input number back to 0 when a new option is selected?

Tags: html, input, return-value, html-select

I want to change/reset the input field back to zero when a new option is selected. I can set the value back to 0 but I want to have that displayed in the input field.

```js
function inputField() {

  var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
  weight = 0;

  console.log(weight);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="pickOne" onChange="inputField()">
    <option id="optionOne" value="1">1</option>
    <option id="optionTwo" value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</form>

<input type="number" id="weight">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function inputField() {
  var weight = document.getElementById("weight");
  weight.value = 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="pickOne" onChange="inputField()">
    <option id="optionOne" value="1">1</option>
    <option id="optionTwo" value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</form>

<input type="number" id="weight">
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I had to remove the .value from the var. Thank you!